# FuelUX spinbox - use custom strings array

Tags: fuelux

Is it possible to leverage FuelUX spinbox to cycle/scroll through array of custom strings?

This is an example of what I mean, but it's a jQueryUI implementation:

```
Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.
Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code 
toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut.
For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MartynDavis/gzmvc2ds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something quick and dirty based on FuelUX spinbox:

```
/*
 * Fuel UX SpinStrings
 * https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014 ExactTarget
 * Licensed under the BSD New license.
 */

// -- BEGIN UMD WRAPPER PREFACE --

// For more information on UMD visit:
// https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/jqueryPlugin.js

(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // if AMD loader is available, register as an anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // Node/CommonJS
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // OR use browser globals if AMD is not present
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {
    // -- END UMD WRAPPER PREFACE --

    // -- BEGIN MODULE CODE HERE --

    var old = $.fn.spinstrings;

    // SPINSTRINGS CONSTRUCTOR AND PROTOTYPE

    var SpinStrings = function SpinStrings(element, options) {
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.$element.find('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
            //keep spinstrings from submitting if they forgot to say type="button" on their spinner buttons
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        if ($.isPlainObject(options) && 'options' in options) {
            if (!$.isArray(options.options)) {
                delete options.options;
            } else {
                options.min = 0;
                options.max = options.options.length - 1;
                if (options.value && ((idx = options.options.indexOf(options.value)) > -1)) {
                    options.index = idx;
                } else {
                    options.index = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.spinstrings.defaults, options);

        if (this.options.index < this.options.min) {
            this.options.index = this.options.min;
        } else if (this.options.max < this.options.index) {
            this.options.index = this.options.max;
        }

        this.$input = this.$element.find('.spinstrings-input');
        this.$input.on('focusout.fu.spinstrings', this.$input, $.proxy(this.change, this));
        this.$element.on('keydown.fu.spinstrings', this.$input, $.proxy(this.keydown, this));
        this.$element.on('keyup.fu.spinstrings', this.$input, $.proxy(this.keyup, this));

        this.bindMousewheelListeners();
        this.mousewheelTimeout = {};

        this.$element.on('click.fu.spinstrings', '.spinstrings-up', $.proxy(function () {
            this.step(true);
        }, this));
        this.$element.on('click.fu.spinstrings', '.spinstrings-down', $.proxy(function () {
            this.step(false);
        }, this));

        this.lastValue = this.options.value;

        this.render();

        if (this.options.disabled) {
            this.disable();
        }
    };

    // Truly private methods

    var _applyLimits = function(value) {
        // if unreadable
        if (isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
            return value;
        }

        // if not within range return the limit
        if (value > this.options.max) {
            if (this.options.cycle) {
                value = this.options.min;
            } else {
                value = this.options.max;
            }
        } else if (value < this.options.min) {
            if (this.options.cycle) {
                value = this.options.max;
            } else {
                value = this.options.min;
            }
        }

        return value;
    };

    SpinStrings.prototype = {
        constructor: SpinStrings,

        destroy: function destroy() {
            this.$element.remove();
            // any external bindings
            // [none]
            // set input value attrbute
            this.$element.find('input').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
            });
            // empty elements to return to original markup
            // [none]
            // returns string of markup
            return this.$element[0].outerHTML;
        },

        render: function render() {
            this.setValue(this.getDisplayValue());
        },

        change: function change() {
            this.setValue(this.getDisplayValue());

            this.triggerChangedEvent();
        },

        triggerChangedEvent: function triggerChangedEvent() {
            var currentValue = this.getValue();
            if (currentValue === this.lastValue) return;
            this.lastValue = currentValue;

            // Primary changed event
            this.$element.trigger('changed.fu.spinstrings', currentValue);
        },

        step: function step(isIncrease) {
            //refresh value from display before trying to increment in case they have just been typing before clicking the nubbins
            this.setValue(this.getDisplayValue());
            var newVal;

            if (isIncrease) {
                newVal = this.options.index + this.options.step;
            } else {
                newVal = this.options.index - this.options.step;
            }

            newVal = _applyLimits.call(this, newVal);
            newVal = this.getOptionByIndex(newVal);

            this.setValue(newVal);
        },

        getDisplayValue: function getDisplayValue() {
            var inputValue = this.$input.val();
            var value = (!!inputValue) ? inputValue : this.options.value;
            return value;
        },

        /**
         * @param string value
         */
        setDisplayValue: function setDisplayValue(value) {
            this.$input.val(value);
        },

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        getValue: function getValue() {
            return this.options.value;
        },

        /**
         * @param string val
         */
        setValue: function setValue(val) {
            var intVal = this.getIndexByOption(val);

            //cache the pure int value
            this.options.value = val;
            this.options.index = intVal;

            //display number
            this.setDisplayValue(val);

            return this;
        },

        value: function value(val) {
            if (val || val === 0) {
                return this.setValue(val);
            } else {
                return this.getValue();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get string's position in array of options.
         *
         * @param string value
         * @return integer
         */
        getIndexByOption: function(value) {
            ret = null;
            if (this.options.options) {
                ret = this.options.options.indexOf(value);
            }
            return ret;
        },

        /**
         * Get option string by index.
         *
         * @param integer index
         * @return string
         */
        getOptionByIndex: function(value) {
            ret = null;
            if (this.options.options[value]) {
                ret = this.options.options[value];
            }
            return ret;
        },

        disable: function disable() {
            this.options.disabled = true;
            this.$element.addClass('disabled');
            this.$input.attr('disabled', '');
            this.$element.find('button').addClass('disabled');
        },

        enable: function enable() {
            this.options.disabled = false;
            this.$element.removeClass('disabled');
            this.$input.removeAttr('disabled');
            this.$element.find('button').removeClass('disabled');
        },

        keydown: function keydown(event) {
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
            if (keyCode === 38) {
                this.step(true);
            } else if (keyCode === 40) {
                this.step(false);
            } else if (keyCode === 13) {
                this.change();
            }
        },

        keyup: function keyup(event) {
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;

            if (keyCode === 38 || keyCode === 40) {
                this.triggerChangedEvent();
            }
        },

        bindMousewheelListeners: function bindMousewheelListeners() {
            var inputEl = this.$input.get(0);
            if (inputEl.addEventListener) {
                //IE 9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
                inputEl.addEventListener('mousewheel', $.proxy(this.mousewheelHandler, this), false);
                // Firefox
                inputEl.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', $.proxy(this.mousewheelHandler, this), false);
            } else {
                // IE <9
                inputEl.attachEvent('onmousewheel', $.proxy(this.mousewheelHandler, this));
            }
        },

        mousewheelHandler: function mousewheelHandler(event) {
            if (!this.options.disabled) {
                var e = window.event || event;// old IE support
                var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
                var self = this;

                clearTimeout(this.mousewheelTimeout);
                this.mousewheelTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    self.triggerChangedEvent();
                }, 300);

                if (delta > 0) {//ACE
                    this.step(true);
                } else {
                    this.step(false);
                }

                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    e.returnValue = false;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    };


    // SPINSTRINGS PLUGIN DEFINITION

    $.fn.spinstrings = function spinstrings(option) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        var methodReturn;

        var $set = this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data = $this.data('fu.spinstrings');
            var options = typeof option === 'object' && option;

            if (!data) {
                $this.data('fu.spinstrings', (data = new SpinStrings(this, options)));
            }

            if (typeof option === 'string') {
                methodReturn = data[option].apply(data, args);
            }
        });

        return (methodReturn === undefined) ? $set : methodReturn;
    };

    // value needs to be 0 for this.render();
    $.fn.spinstrings.defaults = {
        value: null,
        index: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 0,
        step: 1,
        disabled: false,
        cycle: true
    };

    $.fn.spinstrings.Constructor = SpinStrings;

    $.fn.spinstrings.noConflict = function noConflict() {
        $.fn.spinstrings = old;
        return this;
    };


    // DATA-API

    $(document).on('mousedown.fu.spinstrings.data-api', '[data-initialize=spinstrings]', function (e) {
        var $control = $(e.target).closest('.spinstrings');
        if (!$control.data('fu.spinstrings')) {
            $control.spinstrings($control.data());
        }
    });

    // Must be domReady for AMD compatibility
    $(function () {
        $('[data-initialize=spinstrings]').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.data('fu.spinstrings')) {
                $this.spinstrings($this.data());
            }
        });
    });

    // -- BEGIN UMD WRAPPER AFTERWORD --
}));
// -- END UMD WRAPPER AFTERWORD --
```

Mark-up & style:

```
<style>
    .spinstrings {position:relative;display:inline-block;margin-left:-2px}
    .spinstrings input {height:26px;color:#444444;font-size:12px;padding:0 5px;margin:0 !important;width:100px}
    .spinstrings input[readonly] {background-color:#ffffff !important}
    .spinstrings .spinstrings-arrows {position:absolute;right:5px;height:22px;width:12px;background:transparent;top:1px}
    .spinstrings .spinstrings-arrows i.fa {position:absolute;display:block;font-size:16px;line-height:10px;width:12px;cursor:pointer}
    .spinstrings .spinstrings-arrows i.fa:hover {color:#307ecc}
    .spinstrings .spinstrings-arrows i.fa.spinstrings-up {top:0}
    .spinstrings .spinstrings-arrows i.fa.spinstrings-down {bottom:0}
</style>
<div class="spinstrings" id="mySpinStrings">
    <input type="text" class="spinstrings-input" readonly="readonly">
    <div class="spinstrings-arrows"><i class="fa fa-caret-up spinstrings-up"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down spinstrings-down"></i></div>
</div>
```

Init as:

```
    $('#mySpinStrings', expiryControlsW).spinstrings({
        options: ['day', 'week', 'month'],
        value: 'week'
    });
```

That's it, folks!

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box, no.

You'd have to modify this portion of [spinbox](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/3.13.0/js/spinbox.js) to make newVal be set by accessing your desired array instead of doing maths:

```
    step: function step(isIncrease) {
        //refresh value from display before trying to increment in case they have just been typing before clicking the nubbins
        this.setValue(this.getDisplayValue());
        var newVal;

        if (isIncrease) {
            newVal = this.options.value + this.options.step;
        } else {
            newVal = this.options.value - this.options.step;
        }

        newVal = newVal.toFixed(5);

        this.setValue(newVal + this.unit);
    },
```

Comment: It's surprising that there's no such component out there already.